# 'DatasetGroupBy' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, dask, python-xarray

I have multiple netCDF4 datasets which contain monthly weather data for an entire year. After extracting monthly data using groupby method in xarray, I am not able to get the statistical information like mean, std from that grouped result. It gives error while performing basic arithmetic operations.

I have grouped the monthly data in the following way:

```py
monthTime = ds.groupby('time.month')
```

After this, when I want to get the temperature values, it shows an error:

```py
monthTime['temp']
```

```py
TypeError: 'DatasetGroupBy' object is not subscriptable
```

While calculating mean of the monthTime variable, I get this result:

```py
monthTime.mean()
```

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (month: 12)
Coordinates:
  * month    (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Data variables:
    temp       (month) float64 dask.array<shape=(12,), chunksize=(1,)>
```

How to calculate the mean and standard deviation. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Group-by` works as `Split-Apply-Combine`. You can read more about it in the pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) which has great examples on it.

When you group your data by months, the indexing won't work because you have to first apply some function like mean, etc and recombine it into Datastructure. However, if you want to view the grouped object you can convert it to list

```
list(monthTime)
```

In your case, you get the mean of your variable `temp`. Monthtime is not a variable of your Datastructure. I think for your analysis you want mean or std of your variable `temp`. So, the approach would be:

```
ds.temp.groupby('time.month').mean()
# similarly you can apply any other functions
```

Comment: `ds.temp.groupby('time.month').mean()` does calculate the mean, but does not displays the calculated values. To see the calcualated values, I simply used `ds.temp.groupby('time.month').mean().values`. It was kind of a silly question though.